# How to disable automatic superscript

Tags: keyboard-layout

Every time I type `x`+ `^`+ `2` in kate or any other text editor I get `x²`. There is a way to change this behavior to get instead `x^2`, that is, to disable automatic superscripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the ^ symbol on the keyboard layout you are using is a "dead key" (`dead_circumflex`). You can do:

x + ^ + ^ + 2

or

x + ^ + <kbd>Space</kbd> + 2

to achieve what you want.

Or you can switch to some other keyboard layout or customize the layout you are using.

Comment: ok, I will try to configure the dead keys in my keyboard layout, thank you